# Cannot connect to gitlab.com or github.com from openshift-jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, openshift

I just installed the latest openshift origin, and created a jenkins project from the provided templates, but I cannot seem to even ping any git repos (gitlab.com or github.com) from this jenkins instance.  The jenkins instance has the respective plugins installed and seems to be working fine otherwise.  From doing an "oc rsh " into the pod, and pinging gitlab.com, i get timeouts, though I'm not sure if this is expected or not.

I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious, but cannot figure out what that is.

Comment: It can be a proxy problem. Have you tried adding the repo URLs as no-proxy host in Jenkins?

Comment: i have not.  is that something that should be configured within jenkins or as part of the pod's startup?